# how can i get the path to one exe programatically while working with another file at other location

Tags: c#, .net

i want to call an exe file(abc.exe) from another application(hello)

how can i get the path of abc.exe file programatically so that i can use it to invoke abc.exe

abc.exe is not the part of executing assembly
so
assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [system.diagnostics.process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28VS.71%29.aspx) Class's capabilities to do this.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
/// <summary>
/// Shell for the sample.
/// </summary>
public class MyProcess
{
    // These are the Win32 error code for file not found or access denied.
    const int ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND =2;
    const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5;

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints a file with a .doc extension.
    /// </summary>
    public void PrintDoc()
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();

        try
        {
            // Get the path that stores user documents.
            string myDocumentsPath = 
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = myDocumentsPath + "\\MyFile.doc"; 
            myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
        }
        catch (Win32Exception e)
        {
            if(e.NativeErrorCode == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + ". Check the path.");
            } 

            else if (e.NativeErrorCode == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
            {
                // Note that if your word processor might generate exceptions
                // such as this, which are handled first.
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + 
                    ". You do not have permission to print this file.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but how to get the path of exe file

Comment: Please clarify more? What do you mean by getting the path? Finding the absolute path when given just the file name?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to launch a separate process.

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\program files\hello\abc.exe"
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: @"c:\program files\hello\abc.exe"

i cannot set path like this,it should be relative

Comment: You can use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() to get the current directory, and build a relative path from that.